# Porting a winform app to monodevelop on mac

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, monodevelop

I'm tryng to port a winforms app created in Visual Studio to Mac with monodevelop. After resolving compiling errors, when I run the program, the application outputs these exceptions:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.set_Lines (System.String[] value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase:set_Lines (string[])

  at WindowsFormsApplication1.Main_Form.amp_portante_ValueChanged (System.Object Sender) [0x00025] in /Users/giuseppe/Desktop/CRUZER/Csound Converter/WindowsFormsApplication1/Main_Form.cs:381

  at KnobControl.KnobControl.OnValueChanged (System.Object sender) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

  at KnobControl.KnobControl.set_Value (Int32 value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) KnobControl.KnobControl:set_Value (int)
  at WindowsFormsApplication1.Main_Form.textb2_TextChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00085] in /Users/giuseppe/Desktop/CRUZER/Csound Converter/WindowsFormsApplication1/Main_Form.cs:1023 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnTextChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.OnTextChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.set_Text (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.set_Text (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WindowsFormsApplication1.Main_Form.SimpleFM_Conf () [0x00058] in /Users/giuseppe/Desktop/CRUZER/Csound Converter/WindowsFormsApplication1/Main_Form.cs:45 
  at WindowsFormsApplication1.Main_Form.Main_Form_Load (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00012] in /Users/giuseppe/Desktop/CRUZER/Csound Converter/WindowsFormsApplication1/Main_Form.cs:359 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The application works perfectly in Visual Studio and I have no idea what I should do.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint inside `Main_Form.textb2_TextChanged` or `Main_Form.amp_portante_ValueChanged` and see if you can figure out what's null from there. It almost looks like your KnobControl is null, but I'm not used to monodevelop stack traces so I may very well be wrong :)

Comment: i placed the breakpoints and the application stops but i don't know how to see what's null from here...i'm not experienced at debugging

Comment: Hm, well, in Visual Studio a mouseover over the variable will show the value, not sure about MonoDevelop.

Comment: textb2 and amp_portante are not null they have a int value

Comment: Can you post your code inside amp_portante_ValueChanged ()?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a custom control (KnobControl) which you can't instantiate.

Maybe you don't have this control or this control doesn't compile with mono.

Take a look at line 381 in Main_Form.cs

Regards,